# Response.End() not preventing appended html

Tags: c#, webforms

There are many (*many*) SO and other threads about the correct use of `Response.End()` however, none appear to match behaviour we're seeing in code that is unchanged for years.

Behaviour: When downloading a file, the HTML content of the page is appended to the file contents.

**Project Type:** WebForms

**.NET Version:** 4.6.2 | 4.5.0 |  4.0.0

**VS Version:** 2015 | 2013 | 2012 (with/without safe mode turned on)

**WebHost:** IIS Express (default settings)

Create a blank WebForms project. Remove all references but;

- System
- System.Web

Default.aspx (stipped from default template)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestDownload2.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Sample page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="_uiExportBtn" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="_uiExportBtn_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace TestDownload
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;

    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void _uiExportBtn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/File1.txt");
                FileInfo fileDetails = new FileInfo(filePath);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                   "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));  // strip out the path
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileDetails.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                Response.WriteFile(filePath);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Thread.ResetAbort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Contents of File1.txt

```
File with sample data that can be downloaded.
```

Contents of file when Download is clicked;

```
File with sample data that can be downloaded.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Sample page
</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTQ2OTkzNDMyMWRk3Rw04QLdhpy5d4I1K2wRBGQwJyDyRwQJv3qrWVnmZOk=" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="CA0B0334" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAIM+aT11BIx7AHRURAAeZqgtB4HvaHnJdET69NHLAgDcsjxSqzk6G3joivJ/c73mKUQf4CSnfdxrC8NepO7KQg3" />
</div>
        <input type="submit" name="_uiExportBtn" value="Download" id="_uiExportBtn" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
After a lot of experimenting with different browsers, VS versions, .NET versions in an effort to narrow this down, it appears that the issue is the specified MIME type as registered on IIS.

And it seems that this is the second time I've run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17719935/1838819). I used a similar workaround but I'm still left mystified by the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I think I can offer a possible explanation as to why we get the behaviour above. As specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types) on how to set up MIME types and how browsers interpret them, it would seem that by specifying `text/palin` or `text/csv` on my file that the browser interprets this the same as `text/html` (the page already displayed) and adds the current page content to the HTTP response of the file.

It's important to note that the HTML appended isn't actually transmitted as part of the file response yet the browser will still attach it if it thinks the file is the same type of content as the page.

As to a solution and following on from what the article describes, in order to separate out a file from the rest of the HTTP response, it should be marked as `application/octet-stream`, *especially* in instances where the file actually contains text very easily interpreted as HTML content such as `.txt` or `.csv` files.